# Insert image in echo line - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce

Maybe this is to simple for you but...Not to me :(

I need to put some small icon right before the sentence printed by this line:

```
echo "<p class='woopr-product-message'>".$message."</p>";
```

The sentence show by this code is:

> Buy now and get X points

Any idea how to achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: Do you just want an `<img>` element?  Have you tried adding one?

Comment: Try using double quotes where your telling it what class to be. Escape them like this \”

Comment: Maybe apply a background image on the `woopr-product-message` class? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Bigbob556677 Either quote type is allowed for encapsulation in HTML/PHP (and in the majority of languages).

Comment: @FlashThunder that's a PHP echo, so I would think it has everything to do with PHP. The context is Woocommerce, although that's an unnecessary tag.

Comment: `echo '<img src="icon src"><p class="woopr-product-message">' . $message . '</p>';` or `echo '<i class="fa fontawesome icon class"></i><p class="woopr-product-message">' . $message . '</p>';` if using font awesome icons.

Comment: @FlashThunder it is PHP, they are trying to figure out how to add the element to the PHP

Comment: @disinfor thank you so much but I tried the first option and works but the image is not at the same sentence's line. :)

Comment: @Fran I only gave you the PHP necessary. You'll need to add CSS styles to format the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple add code  before variable

```
<?php
    $message = "Hello World";
    echo "<p class='woopr-product-message'><img src='https://number-1.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/icon-address-grey.png' /> ".$message."</p>";
?>
```

or using fontawesome icon

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
<?php 
    $message = "Hello World";
    echo "<p class='woopr-product-message'><i class='fas fa-home'></i> ".$message."</p>";
?>
```